# python : pass regex back-reference value to method

Tags: python, regex, backreference

I have this content:

```
Data1
import filename.in
Data2
```

and want to replace `import filename.in` line with the content of `filename` file, so I use this:

```
content = re.sub(r'import\s+(.*)\s+\n', '\n' + read_file('\1') + '\n', content)
```

`read_file(in)` returns the content of file `in`.

```
def read_file(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return f.read()
```

the problem is that back-ref `\1` does not eval to `filename.in` :

```
No such file or directory: '\\1'
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read_file(..)` is called not by the `re.sub`. `'\1'` is used literally as a filename. In addition to that, `\1` is interpreted `\x01`.

To do that you need to pass a replacement function instead:

```
content = re.sub(
    r'import\s+(.*)\s+\n',
    lambda m: '\n' + read_file(m.group(1)) + '\n',  # `m` is a match object
    content)
```